# PHP cookie. how to access cookie domain

Tags: php, cookies

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600, "www.example.com");
```

using PHP if i set a cookie this way how can i access the value of the domain in $_COOKIE or some other way? Plz Help

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain, secure, httponly);
```

> [Domain](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):The domain that the cookie is available to. Setting the domain to 'www.example.com' will make the cookie available in the
>   www subdomain and higher subdomains. Cookies available to a lower
>   domain, such as 'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains,
>   such as 'www.example.com'. Older browsers still implementing the
>   deprecated

***So there is no way to access the domain using PHP.***

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the domain name of cookie using PHP. May be this is possible through javascript on client side.

Answer (score -1):

Access it like

```
$domain = $_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
```

Comment: This gets the value of the cookie, not the domain it was set to.